# Remote erase of Android phone that's been turned off

Tags: google-account, security

I am trying to do a remote lock and factory reset of my Android phone (Samsung S7 Edge) which has been stolen. I've gone to [Android Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) and [Google's "Find your phone" page](https://myaccount.google.com/find-your-phone) and both say the phone last synced an hour ago and can't locate the device, which means the thieves probably turned the phone off.

Anyway, I've set up both the "Lock" option (where a password is required to open the phone) and the "Erase" option (where the phone is reset to the factory default), and both try and fail to find the phone. If I then refresh the respective pages, the options are available once again, without any demonstration that my previous requests were stored.

Does this mean that I can only request these operations when the phone is on? Or does the request remain registered in the system and, as soon as the phone powers on and connects to the network, it performs the requested operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The request is queued... If the erase is successful you will receive an email with the time, date, and location (if available) of the device when the command was successful.